# Django - models.Datefield()

Tags: python, django-models

'''
# DAY 2

```
day_2_date = models.DateField()
day_2_instructor_position = models.CharField(
    max_length=50,
    choices=POSITION_CHOICE,
    default=LEAD_INSTRUCTOR)
day_2_start_time = models.TimeField()
day_2_end_time = models.TimeField()
day_2_hours_worked = models.IntegerField()
```

'''

Questions for the Django Peeps:

Why is when I first run python manage.py makemigrations, then migrate, there are no issues with leaving the fields as they are with no default value. Now when I added another day, (day_3), and want to run the same commands, it gives me the following error.

*You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'day_3_date' to instructor_timesheet without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).*

New to Django and coding in general.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a new column to a database table that has rows already, and the column is not allow to be `NULL`, then you must provide another value the existing rows will get for this field.